# How to quickly compute the inverse of 3x3 matrix that only has non-zero value on diagonals?

Tags: matrices

Does anyone know if there is a short cut to compute the inverse of the matrices of the form

$\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & c
\end{pmatrix}$

and

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & a \\
0 & b & 0 \\
c & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note first that inverses are in fact unique and if one of $a,b,$ or $c$ were zero then the matrix would be deficient (no inverse).

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & c
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{a} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{b} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{c}
\end{pmatrix} = I_3
$$

So $\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{a} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{b} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{c}
\end{pmatrix}$ is the inverse of your first matrix.

Similarly

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & a \\
0 & b & 0 \\
c & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{c} \\
0 & \frac{1}{b} & 0 \\
\frac{1}{a} & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = I_3$$

As for how I knew that these would be the inverses, note that for two diagonal matrices, $\Lambda = diag[\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n]$ and $\Delta = diag[\delta_1, \delta_2, \dots, \delta_n]$ you have $\Lambda\cdot \Delta = \Delta\cdot \Lambda = diag[\lambda_1\delta_1, \lambda_2\delta_2,\dots, \lambda_n\delta_n]$.  For $\Lambda\cdot \Delta = I_n$ you would need each $\lambda_i\cdot\delta_i = 1$ and so $\delta_i = \frac{1}{\lambda_i}$.

For the second matrix, note that it is a diagonal matrix times the permutation matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$.  Composing the inverse of the permutation matrix (itself in this case) with the inverse of the diagonal matrix brought the desired result.